# jQuery Animate table <td> elements when changing colspan values for them

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, html-table

Ok, I am changing colspans on `<td>` elements within a table at runtime, however, I think it would look nicer to have jQuery animate the change on the `<td>` elements within a table as the colspan changes (gets higher or reduces).  The changes to the `<td>` colspan attributes are being done via text links (probably will be changed to images later on).

But I'm basically wondering if there is a way to do this in jQuery so that as I change the colspan, it will automatically slide it bigger or smaller with an animation effect?  Not sure if I should use slideToggle, or animate, or something else to accomplish this.  Can someone help me with ideas on what to use for this, and perhaps a bit of example code would be nice also.  But basically, really interested in how the table would have to be set up to accomplish this also.

Thanks guys :)

Comment: Try overlaying an absolutely positioned div and have it grow or shrink immediately after changing the colspan?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by overlay.  So, do you mean that the `<div>` would contain the table inside of it?  Also, should I use animate or slideToggle for this?  And how would I envoke animate when a change is made to the colspan exactly?  Will I need to give the table a height and/or width property.  I already have a width set to 100%, but the height will mess things up if I give it a height...

Comment: Is there anyway to put a div inside of the `td` elements that will automatically animate (grow and/or shrink) if the `td` element gets bigger/smaller in size?

Comment: You could put the div inside the table cell `<td><div>content</div></td>` and then when you increase the colspan on the td, first specify the div width to the current div width and then use animate to get it to fit the new td's width (by detecting the cell's width and telling the div to expand/shrink to that size). Or you could have an absolutely positioned div (with respect to the page) on top of the cell (z-index) and you do the same thing. The second approach won't constrain the content of the cell, though